# Approximation of ideal capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance

Capacitors are often approximated as infinite conducting plates. I find this approximation surprising since the capacitors I've seen in circuits are only a few centimetres big.

For all the derivations of formulas and laws for capacitors my book assumes an infinitely large plate. Since the conductors I've seen are incredibly small compared to infinite plates shouldn't all laws be invalid since the assumed approximation of its size is completely invalid?

Answer (score 2):

For infinite plates, the electric field between the plates is uniform everywhere regardless of the distance separating the plates.

However, if the width of the plates is *much* larger than the distance between the plates, the electric field is *approximately* uniform over much of the area and, thus, the capacitor equation *approximately* holds.

From the Wikipedia article "[Capacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor#Parallel-plate_model)":

> Assuming that the width of the plates is much greater than their
>   separation d, the electric field near the centre of the device will be
>   uniform

For an example of the corrections required when the above does not hold, see this paper:  "[Form and Capacitance of Parallel-Plate Capacitors](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~cgshirl/Documents/Nishiyama%20Nakamura.pdf)"

Comment: I would say if *both* dimensions of the plates are much greater than the spacing of the plates. Also consider that the presence of dielectric with \$\epsilon_R >1\$ the dimension of the plates reduces the relative importance of the edge effects.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, the above assumes the width is smaller or equal to the length.